# Spring Java: Load All XML Configuration file from Jar Using Spring 4, JDK 8 and Tomcat 8

Tags: spring, tomcat, exception, configuration

I am create maven multi-mdule project, in which my all configuration files are in maven one module, and i am trying to inject config module jar into web war, so run time tomcat can load all configuration files. But when i deploy the war file, tomcat thrown an exception. I have JDK 8 and Tomcat 8:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [config/spring-security.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/webapps/empirecl-web/WEB-INF/lib/empirecl-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: authentication-provider element cannot be used with other attributes when using 'ref' attribute
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/webapps/empirecl-web/WEB-INF/lib/empirecl-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/config/spring-security.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:274)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
```

My Maven module structure as below:

[image]

Follwoing my web module pom:

```
<artifactId>empirecl-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Start Custom Module Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netsol</groupId>
        <artifactId>empirecl-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Following is `applicationContext.xml` code:

```
<!-- for database configuration -->
<import resource="config/db-configuration.xml" />

<!-- for Spring security -->
<import resource="config/spring-security.xml" /> 
<import resource="tiles-context.xml" />
```

Follwoing is my `web.xml` file code:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:**/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

I think the problem is that, applicationContext.xml easily find by container, but `applicationContext.xml` file contain some imports of another configuration files, that imports generate an error. So, how i load all configuration files from jars?

Thanks in Advance

---

I update this question because with the help of `M. Deinum` i found my half solution. The solution is that use this `<import resource="classpath*:/config/spring-security.xml" />` syntax instead of `<import resource="config/db-configuration.xml" />`. But the problem is solve with `db-configuration` file only. The `spring-security` configuration still generate following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:/config/spring-security.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/webapps/empirecl-web/WEB-INF/lib/empirecl-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: authentication-provider element cannot be used with other attributes when using 'ref' attribute
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/webapps/empirecl-web/WEB-INF/lib/empirecl-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/config/spring-security.xml]
```

In the above image, you can also check the `spring-security.xml` already exist.

Comment: Don't use relative paths. Prefix with `classpath:`. Relatives paths work from the root loaded file not the file containing the imports.

Comment: if prefix with `classpath:` it also thrown an exception. firstly i was use with `classpath:`.

Comment: It should work then there is something else wrong with your setup. Regardless of that you need the `classpath:` prefix.

Comment: with `classpath:` prefix follwoing exception will thrown: `org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/config/spring-security.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-8.0.8/webapps/empirecl-web/WEB-INF/lib/empirecl-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml];`

Comment: prefix with `classpath*:` instead.

Comment: already trying this, the same exception will throw.

Comment: We use the same setup here, without problems. So if you really tried prefixing your imports with `classpath*:` then you have some other problems. You are using windows might be that your path is too long?

Comment: Hey @M.Deinum now i notice one this, in the above `applicationContext.xml` code i declare db and spring-security files in import. but the problem is with spring-security. because now i try, to comment spring-security and the db config file run successfully. i don't know what is the problem with spring security.

Comment: Mayeb it doesn't exists. Maybe it contains an error, maybe you forgot to include required dependencies. I have no idea especially not without seeing the actual error. And please update your question instead of adding stacktraces as comments!

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for you help. i really solve my half of problem with your help.

Comment: I think "Configuration problem: authentication-provider element cannot be used with other attributes when using 'ref' attribute" says that there is some error in your security xml file. Can you please show your security xml contents?

Comment: Yes @GurminderSingh, `<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"
   user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
  <!-- <authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" /> -->
 </authentication-manager>` this is authentication-manager configure bean. Sir, i am also think about this.

Comment: Can you try after removing "user-service-ref" attribute from authentication-provider tag?

Comment: sir i was also try this and know, the example was run. :D

Comment: Are you using like this:  "<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider ref='daoAuthenticationProvider' />
 </authentication-manager>

 <b:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
  class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <b:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
 </b:bean>". If not, try like this.

Comment: sir, i am using dao authentication manager, with custom implementation of `UserDetailService` provide by spring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57252/discussion-between-gurminder-singh-and-harmeet-singh).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for you help, but now i wanted to load `spring-security.xml` file from `WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml`. when i put `<import resource="classpath*:/config/spring-security.xml" />` this import tag, the tomcat run, but the `spring-security.xml` file not load.

Comment: If it isn't loaded it doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: my jar have multiple xml config file, in same jar, if i need to import one fie to another, this pattern is used. But if we import files from jar, which pattern we need ?